# Scikit Learn SVC decision_function and predict

Tags: python, numpy, svm, scikit-learn

I'm trying to understand the relationship between decision_function and predict, which are instance methods of SVC  (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html). So far I've gathered that decision function returns pairwise scores between classes. I was under the impression that predict chooses the class that maximizes its pairwise score, but I tested this out and got different results. Here's the code I was using to try and understand the relationship between the two. First I generated the pairwise score matrix, and then I printed out the class that has maximal pairwise score which was different than the class predicted by clf.predict.

```
        result = clf.decision_function(vector)[0]
        counter = 0
        num_classes = len(clf.classes_)
        pairwise_scores = np.zeros((num_classes, num_classes))
        for r in xrange(num_classes):
            for j in xrange(r + 1, num_classes):
                pairwise_scores[r][j] = result[counter]
                pairwise_scores[j][r] = -result[counter]
                counter += 1

        index = np.argmax(pairwise_scores)
        class = index_star / num_classes
        print class
        print clf.predict(vector)[0]
```

Does anyone know the relationship between these predict and decision_function?

Comment: "decision function returns pairwise scores between classes" is incorrect. It should be the "score for each class" as it's written in the documentation page for `decision_function` part: "Distance of the samples X to the separating hyperplane."

Comment: @justhalf: no, the OP is correct. `sklearn.svm.SVC` uses a pairwise (one-vs-one) decomposition by default and returns distances to all of the n(n-1)/2 hyperplanes for each sample.

Comment: Oops, yes, I remembered reading that somewhere. but was misled by the documentation. Sorry!

Comment: After trying to answer, I think that bcorso's answer should be the one. The relationship is actually based on the code he translated from the C++ implementation: `decision = decision_function(params, sv, nv, a, b, X); votes = [(i if decision[p] > 0 else j) for p,(i,j) in enumerate((i,j) for i in range(len(cs)) for j in range(i+1,len(cs)))]`. The highest vote out of `votes` is basically what `predict` does.

Comment: Does anyone have the link to the official documentation of the decision_function() please? I can't find it online.

Answer (score 59):

I don't fully understand your code, but let's go through the example in the documentation page you referenced:

```
import numpy as np
X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [1, 1], [2, 1]])
y = np.array([1, 1, 2, 2])
from sklearn.svm import SVC
clf = SVC()
clf.fit(X, y)
```

Now let's apply both the decision_function() and predict() to the samples:

```
clf.decision_function(X)
clf.predict(X)
```

The output we get is:

```
array([[-1.00052254],
       [-1.00006594],
       [ 1.00029424],
       [ 1.00029424]])
array([1, 1, 2, 2])
```

And that is easy to interpret: The decision function tells us on which side of the hyperplane generated by the classifier we are (and how far we are away from it). Based on that information, the estimator then labels the examples with the corresponding label.

Comment: It's easy to interpret because this is a binary example. In the multiclass case, `SVC.decision_function` gets more complicated.

Answer (score 31):

For those interested, I'll post a quick example of the `predict` function translated from C++ ([here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/svm/src/libsvm/svm.cpp#L2836)) to python:

```
# I've only implemented the linear and rbf kernels
def kernel(params, sv, X):
    if params.kernel == 'linear':
        return [np.dot(vi, X) for vi in sv]
    elif params.kernel == 'rbf':
        return [math.exp(-params.gamma * np.dot(vi - X, vi - X)) for vi in sv]

# This replicates clf.decision_function(X)
def decision_function(params, sv, nv, a, b, X):
    # calculate the kernels
    k = kernel(params, sv, X)

    # define the start and end index for support vectors for each class
    start = [sum(nv[:i]) for i in range(len(nv))]
    end = [start[i] + nv[i] for i in range(len(nv))]

    # calculate: sum(a_p * k(x_p, x)) between every 2 classes
    c = [ sum(a[ i ][p] * k[p] for p in range(start[j], end[j])) +
          sum(a[j-1][p] * k[p] for p in range(start[i], end[i]))
                for i in range(len(nv)) for j in range(i+1,len(nv))]

    # add the intercept
    return [sum(x) for x in zip(c, b)]

# This replicates clf.predict(X)
def predict(params, sv, nv, a, b, cs, X):
    ''' params = model parameters
        sv = support vectors
        nv = # of support vectors per class
        a  = dual coefficients
        b  = intercepts 
        cs = list of class names
        X  = feature to predict       
    '''
    decision = decision_function(params, sv, nv, a, b, X)
    votes = [(i if decision[p] > 0 else j) for p,(i,j) in enumerate((i,j) 
                                           for i in range(len(cs))
                                           for j in range(i+1,len(cs)))]

    return cs[max(set(votes), key=votes.count)]
```

There are a lot of input arguments for `predict` and `decision_function`, but note that these are all used internally in by the model when calling `predict(X)`. In fact, all of the arguments are accessible to you inside the model after fitting:

```
# Create model
clf = svm.SVC(gamma=0.001, C=100.)

# Fit model using features, X, and labels, Y.
clf.fit(X, y)

# Get parameters from model
params = clf.get_params()
sv = clf.support_vectors_ #added missing underscore
nv = clf.n_support_
#a  = clf.dual_coef_
a  = clf._dual_coef_ #use complementary dual coefficients
b  = clf._intercept_
cs = clf.classes_

# Use the functions to predict
print(predict(params, sv, nv, a, b, cs, X))

# Compare with the builtin predict
print(clf.predict(X))
```

Comment: Hey ! Thank for your answer. However, I tried your solution and the results are different...

Comment: Hi, bcorso ! Thank you for your answer but just as @lilouch pointer out I can't obtain the same values. The decision function is described as $\langle \mathbf{w},\mathbf{x} \rangle + b$, and this value must be greater than 1 for the positive class and lower than -1 for the negative class. The problem is that I can't figure out how you do the dot product between the new example and the hyperplane vector. Could you help me out?

Comment: sklearn seems to have two complementary pairs of  dual_coef and intercept, change `a  = clf.dual_coef_` to `a  = clf._dual_coef_` and the output of `decision_function` is the same as `clf._decision_function`, and the result of `predict` also concord with `clf.predict`

Comment: I got a error `ValueError: shapes (60000,784) and (60000,784) not aligned: 784 (dim 1) != 60000 (dim 0)`, change `return [math.exp(-params.gamma * np.dot(vi - X, vi - X)) for vi in sv]` to `return [np.exp(-gamma * np.linalg.norm(vi - X)) for vi in sv]`, and `kernel = clf.kernel`, and `gamma = clf._gamma` maybe work fine.

Answer (score 23):

There's a [really nice Q&A](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/18374/34009) for the multi-class one-vs-one scenario at datascience.sx:

#### Question

> I have a multiclass SVM classifier with labels 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'.
>
> This is the code I'm running:
>
> ```
> >>>print clf.predict([predict_this])
> ['A']
> >>>print clf.decision_function([predict_this])
> [[ 185.23220833   43.62763596  180.83305074  -93.58628288   62.51448055  173.43335293]]
> ```
>
> How can I use the output of decision function to predict the class
>   (A/B/C/D) with the highest probability and if possible, it's value? I
>   have visited https://stackoverflow.com/a/20114601/7760998 but it is
>   for binary classifiers and could not find a good resource which
>   explains the output of decision_function for multiclass classifiers
>   with shape ovo (one-vs-one).
>
> **Edit:**
>
> The above example is for class 'A'. For another input the classifier
>   predicted 'C' and gave the following result in decision_function
>
> ```
> [[ 96.42193513 -11.13296606 111.47424538 -88.5356536 44.29272494 141.0069203 ]]
> ```
>
> For another different input which the classifier predicted as 'C' gave
>   the following result from decision_function,
>
> ```
> [[ 290.54180354 -133.93467605  116.37068951 -392.32251314 -130.84421412   284.87653043]]
> ```
>
> Had it been ovr (one-vs-rest), it would become easier by selecting the
>   one with higher value, but in ovo (one-vs-one) there are `(n * (n -
>   1)) / 2` values in the resulting list.
>
> How to deduce which class would be selected based on the decision
>   function?

#### Answer

> Your link has sufficient resources, so let's go through:
>
> > When you call decision_function(), you get the output from each of the pairwise classifiers (n*(n-1)/2 numbers total). See pages 127 and
> >     128 of "Support Vector Machines for Pattern Classification".
>
> Click on the "page 127 and 128" link (not shown here, but in the
>   Stackoverflow answer). You should see:
>
> [image]
>
> - Python's SVM implementation uses one-vs-one. That's exactly what the book is talking about.
> - For each pairwise comparison, we measure the decision function
> - The decision function is the just the regular binary SVM decision boundary
>
> What does that to do with your question?
>
> - clf.decision_function() will give you the $D$ for each pairwise comparison
> - The class with the most votes win
>
> For instance,
>
> > [[ 96.42193513 -11.13296606 111.47424538 -88.5356536 44.29272494 141.0069203 ]]
>
> is comparing:
>
> > [AB, AC, AD, BC, BD, CD]
>
> We label each of them by the sign. We get:
>
> > [A, C, A, C, B, C]
>
> For instance, 96.42193513 is positive and thus A is the label for AB.
>
> Now we have three C, C would be your prediction. If you repeat my
>   procedure for the other two examples, you will get Python's
>   prediction. Try it!

Comment: Is the intercept values (`b`) supposed to be added or subtracted from the dot product? I looked on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support-vector_machine#Linear_SVM) and it is subtracting, but in the article it is adding. Does it even matter that much? I'm quite concerned because I calculate the decision function as `w.x + b` instead of `w.x - b`.

Comment: While you could ask this at the original, intuitively, using +b instead of -b should result in an inverted b. This should not really be a problem.

Answer (score 20):

When you call `decision_function()`, you get the output from each of the pairwise classifiers (n*(n-1)/2 numbers total). See [pages 127 and 128 of "Support Vector Machines for Pattern Classification"](http://books.google.com/books?id=Uy1pqRzABDgC&pg=PA127&lpg=PA127&dq=svm+argmax+decision+function&source=bl&ots=Vj8lpokb6m&sig=eaxwYaQGt4jt9t6ua5-Z2I79A-s&hl=en&sa=X&ei=-WGOUp7TMuKWiALHvoC4Cg&ved=0CEkQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=svm%20argmax%20decision%20function&f=false).

Each classifier puts in a vote as to what the correct answer is (based on the sign of the output of that classifier); `predict()` returns the class with the most votes.

Comment: Thanks Roman! I tested this out and for the most part it looks like predict is choosing the class that gets the most votes. What I was doing wrong initially was choosing the class with the best cumulative margin score.

Answer (score 3):

They probably have a bit complicated mathematical relation. But if you use the `decision_function` in `LinearSVC` classifier, the relation between those two will be more clear! Because then `decision_function` will give you scores for each class label (not same as SVC) and predict will give the class with the best score.

Answer (score 1):

Predict() follows a pairwise voting scheme which returns the class with most votes over all pairwise comparisons. When two classes score the same, the class with the lowest index is returned.

Below a Python example that applies this voting scheme to the (n*(n-1)/2 pairwise scores as returned by a one-versus-one decision_function().

```py
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn import datasets
from numpy import argmax, zeros
from itertools import combinations

# do pairwise comparisons, return class with most +1 votes
def ovo_vote(classes, decision_function):
    combos = list(combinations(classes, 2))
    votes = zeros(len(classes))
    for i in range(len(decision_function[0])):
        if decision_function[0][i] > 0:
            votes[combos[i][0]] = votes[combos[i][0]] + 1
        else:
            votes[combos[i][1]] = votes[combos[i][1]] + 1
    winner = argmax(votes)
    return classes[winner]

# load the digits data set
digits = datasets.load_digits()

X, y = digits.data, digits.target

# set the SVC's decision function shape to "ovo"
estimator = svm.SVC(gamma=0.001, C=100., decision_function_shape='ovo')

# train SVC on all but the last digit
estimator.fit(X.data[:-1], y[:-1])

# print the value of the last digit
print("To be classified digit: ", y[-1:][0])

# print the predicted class
pred = estimator.predict(X[-1:])
print("Perform classification using predict: ", pred[0])

# get decision function
df = estimator.decision_function(X[-1:])

# print the decision function itself
print("Decision function consists of",len(df[0]),"elements:")
print(df)

# get classes, here, numbers 0 to 9
digits = estimator.classes_

# print which class has most votes
vote = ovo_vote(digits, df)
print("Perform classification using decision function: ", vote)
```