# Decision_function for XGBoost in SKLearn wrapper

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost

I get different results for `model.predict_proba(X)[:,0]` compared to `model.decision_function(X)`for a regular Grad Boost Decision Tree classifier in SKLearn so I know that that is not the same.

I want the scores of the model. To plot ROC curves etc. How can I get the decision function for XGBoost classifier using the SKLearn wrapper? And why is predict_proba different from scores?

Comment: why should they be the same? Have you used the exact same algorithm with the exact same hyperparamters and random seed?

Comment: yes its the same model trained once. I'm asking what the difference between the two functions is.

Comment: what is model.decision_function(X) ? Do you have an API/implementation doc for this?

Comment: It gives you the output of the classifier before a threshold is decided. It varies from algorithm to algorithm. For SVM it is the distance to the decision hyperplane (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20113206/scikit-learn-svc-decision-function-and-predict)

Answer (score 1):

In general, I would not expect the `sklearn.GradientBoostingClassifier` and `xgboost.XGBClassifier` to agree, as those use very different implementations. But there are also conceptual difference between the quantities that you have tried to compare:

> And why is predict_proba different from scores?

Probabilities (output of `model.predict_proba(X)`) are obtained from the scores (output of `model.decision_function(X)`) applying the loss/objective function, see [here for the call to the loss function](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b46/sklearn/ensemble/gradient_boosting.py?utf8=%E2%9C%93#L1581) and [here for the actual transformation](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b46/sklearn/ensemble/gradient_boosting.py#L519).

> I want the scores of the model. To plot ROC curves etc. How can I get the decision function for XGBoost classifier using the SKLearn wrapper?

For the ROC curve you will want to use `xgbmodel.predict_proba(X)[:,1]`, i.e. the second column that correspond to the class `1`.