# Equivalent of scitkit-learn's decision_function?

Tags: python, r, svm

In scikit-learn, one can train a OneClassSVM with rbf kernel; and it will provide a "decision_function" which, when supplying new data to predict, will supposedly tells you the distance from the new data point to the separating hyperplane; (but the interpretation is unimportant to me; more on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20113206/scikit-learn-svc-decision-function-and-predict))

Is there an equivalent to this "decision function" in R?

Here is an example from python:

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.svm import OneClassSVM
iris = datasets.load_iris()
svm = OneClassSVM(kernel='rbf',random_state=1)
svmTrained = svm.fit(iris.data)
svmPred = svm.predict(iris.data[1,:].reshape(1,-1))
svmDist = svm.decision_function(iris.data[1,:].reshape(1,-1))
```

I am interested in duplicating this in R, but am stuck on `svmDist`... here is a start in R:

```
attach(iris)
x <- subset(iris, select=-Species)
svmTrained = svm(x, y = NULL, type = "one-classification", kernel = "radial")
svmPred = predict(svmTrained, newdata = x[1,], type = "probability", 
decision.values = TRUE)
#svmDist = ?
```

The answer to this *may* be buried in trying to translate the C++ [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/svm/src/libsvm/svm.cpp) into R. I will putz with that as time permits, but was hoping something may already exist in some obscure package I've never heard of.

Comment: Voting to close. If you offered R code that constructed a data object and described the task in natural language there might be possiblities for SO-on-topicness.

Comment: (added some code to elucidate)