# OneVsRest predict_proba() and predict() don't match?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I'm using OneVsRestClassifier on a multiclass problem with svm.SVC as the base estimator.
The argmax from the `predict_proba()` does not match the predicted class:

[image: sample]

Is there some normalization going on in the background? How do I get predict_proba() and predict()
to match?

Comment: Please do **not** post code or data in the comments - edit & update your post accordingly!

Answer (score 1):

According to the [scikit learn's SVC documentation on multi-class classification](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#scores-and-probabilities), there can be discrepancies between the output of `predict` and the `argmax` of `predict_proba` (emphasis mine):

> The decision_function method of SVC and NuSVC gives per-class scores for each sample (or a single score per sample in the binary case). When the constructor option probability is set to True, class membership probability estimates (from the methods predict_proba and predict_log_proba) are enabled. In the binary case, the probabilities are calibrated using Platt scaling: logistic regression on the SVM’s scores, fit by an additional cross-validation on the training data. In the multiclass case, this is extended as per Wu et al. (2004).
>
> Needless to say, the cross-validation involved in Platt scaling is an expensive operation for large datasets. **In addition, the probability estimates may be inconsistent with the scores, in the sense that the “argmax” of the scores may not be the argmax of the probabilities**. (E.g., in binary classification, a sample may be labeled by predict as belonging to a class that has probability <½ according to predict_proba.) Platt’s method is also known to have theoretical issues. If confidence scores are required, but these do not have to be probabilities, then it is advisable to set probability=False and use decision_function instead of predict_proba.

You cannot get them to match using a SVC. You can try another model if you need the probabilities. If you do not need probabilities, as stated in the documentation, you can use `decision_function` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20113206/scikit-learn-svc-decision-function-and-predict) for more details.)

Comment: Thank you. I ended up using another model, but CalibratedClassifierCV is also an option if you want SVC and the probabilities